# Edit a word document from Sharepoint 2013 in javascript CSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ms-word, csom

I have a requirement using CSOM JavaScript on SharePoint 2013 to get a Word document from a list, edit the document by searching for text and replacing it and then saving back to a list.  Prefer if document is not visible to the user and this is all done behind the scenes.

1. is this possible?
2. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: I actually ended up doing this in a combined server and Javascript scenario, with the JS calling a web handler and from that manipulating the document in C# using the excellent OpenXmlPowerTools Nuget package, specifically with the TextReplace class.  On issue I found was that if you were replacing with data that contained CRLF then they would be stripped out.  I got around this by getting the code from github and handling replace data with new lines and splitting the data into lines and adding a new XElement(W.br) after each.

Answer (score 0):

Word document is just container with XML files, so I think you can edit that XML files inside it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx